# Image deduction with Pillow and Numpy

Tags: python, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have two images:
[image]

and

[image]

I want to export an image that just has the red "Hello" like:

[image]

So I am running a simple deduction python script:

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

root = '/root/'
im1 = np.asarray(Image.open(root+'1.jpg'))
im2 = np.asarray(Image.open(root+'2.jpg'))

deducted_image = np.subtract(im1, im2)

im = Image.fromarray(np.uint8(deducted_image))
im.save(root+"deduction.jpg")
```

But this returns:

[image]

rather than the above. What am I doing wrong? Also do I need numpy or can I do this with just the `Pillow` Library?

---

## Edit:

It should also work with images like this:

[image]

which my code returns:

[image]

Confused as to why it is so pixelated around the edges!

Comment: Would a patchy version work - https://i.imgur.com/o5mFNFi.jpg?

Comment: No. Also the fact that it is `hello` and `red` are completely just for the purposes of the simple example it could be any collection of colours and any object.

Comment: Also @Divakar why is it patchy?

Comment: Question back at you - Why is the last black background one patchy? The black isn't completely surrounding the "Hello".

Comment: Of my images? I have no idea. Thats what I am asking haha!

Comment: It's because you are using jpg compression for saving and loading images, so np.subtract isn't subtracting the original values, but the compressed values that are slightly off resulting in those patches around Hello sign. So, either use loseless (png, etc) or use complicated blob finding codes (not np.subtract).

Comment: Ohh. Interesting. But if they are both compressed why aren't they matching up with the "Slightly off" ?

Comment: They are not compressed to the same values being two different imgs. The compression depends on image data.

Comment: Read up lossy vs. lossless compression.

Comment: Ahh yes of course @Divakar

Comment: @Maximilian you can use .png in order to eliminate compression artifacts; it's the most widely used lossless format, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is perhaps easier just to set the pixels you don't want in the second image to 0?

```
im = im2.copy()
im[im1 == im2] = 0
im = Image.fromarray(im)
```

seems to work for me (obviously just with bigger artifacts because I used your uploaded JPGs)

[image: Result of script]

It is also possible to do this without numpy:

```
from PIL import ImageChops
from PIL import Image

root = '/root/'
im1 = Image.open(root + '1.jpg')
im2 = Image.open(root + '2.jpg')

def nonzero(a):
    return 0 if a < 10 else 255

mask = Image.eval(ImageChops.difference(im1, im2), nonzero).convert('1')

im = Image.composite(im2, Image.eval(im2, lambda x: 0), mask)
```