# How to get the MSE of each pixel in two images of the same dimension

Tags: python, numpy

I have two images that will be identical in dimensions.

The images are numpy arrays and I am itterating the pixels and aquiring the `r` `g` `b` of each pixel like this:

```
for i in range(len(img1)):
    for j in range(len(img1[0])):
        pimg1 = img1[i][j]
        pimg2 = img2[i][j]

        r1 = pimg1[0]
        r2 = pimg2[0]
        g1 = pimg1[1]
        g2 = pimg2[1]
        b1 = pimg1[2]
        b2 = pimg2[2]
```

I then acquire the MSE between the two pixels like:

```
mse = math.sqrt(((r1 - r2) ** 2) + ((g1 - g2) ** 2) + ((b1 - b2) ** 2))
```

The problem is this is ridiculously slow. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

---

### The final goal

I am looking to make all pixels that have a certain "thresholded" similarity, between the two images, black. And all pixels that have a larger difference the pixel of `img2`.

```
if mse > threshold:
    new_img[i][j] = pimg2
else:
    new_img[i][j] = [0, 0, 0] # black pixel
```

### background image

[image]

### entered image

[image]

---

I am capturing images like:

```
for frame in cam.camera.capture_continuous(raw, format="rgb", use_video_port=True):
    img = frame.array
    cv2.imwrite("image.png", img)
```

I am getting the images like:

```
dir = 'images/compare/'
bg = cv2.imread(dir+'bg.png')
img = cv2.imread(dir+'in.png')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use [`np.linalg.norm`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) on the differences -

```
mse = np.linalg.norm(img1-img2,axis=2)
```

Faster one with [`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html) -

```
d = (img1-img2).astype(float)
mse = np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i->...',d,d))
```

Runtime test -

```
In [46]: np.random.seed(0)
    ...: m,n = 1024,1024
    ...: img1 = np.random.randint(0,255,(m,n,3)).astype(np.uint8)
    ...: img2 = np.random.randint(0,255,(m,n,3)).astype(np.uint8)

In [47]: %timeit np.linalg.norm(img1-img2,axis=2)
10 loops, best of 3: 26.6 ms per loop

In [49]: %%timeit
    ...: d = (img1-img2).astype(float)
    ...: mse = np.sqrt(np.einsum('...i,...i->...',d,d))
100 loops, best of 3: 13 ms per loop
```

---

To create an output array that is set to `black` for pixels that have `MSE` values lesser than a certain threshold `mse_thresh` and select from `img2` otherwise, here are the additional codes -

```
mask = mse >= mse_thresh
out = np.where(mask[...,None], img2, 0)
```

Stitching everything together - Using `einsum` to compute squared `MSE` values and comparing against the squared MSE threshold for major improvement and assigning back the output into `img2` -

```
d = (img1-img2).astype(float)
mse = np.einsum('...i,...i->...',d,d)
img2[mse < mse_thresh**2] = 0
```

Comment: The problem is that this still affects a fps of ~0.1fps to ~0.4fps :(

Comment: @Maximilian Time to change the algorithm it seems :)

Comment: @Maximilian Or would you be okay with writing the result into `img2`?

Comment: @Maximilian Check out the last part (3 lines code).

Comment: Please see the edit in my question where I have added the two test images. the difference extraction returns https://i.imgur.com/4O7ZX3s.png

Comment: I think this is the technique https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27035672/cv-extract-differences-between-two-images

Comment: @Maximilian Use loseless images (png, etc.)? See related discussion - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47265000/image-deduction-with-pillow-and-numpy?noredirect=1#comment81481451_47265000

Comment: currently trying to pre process with blur to no avail

Comment: Please see updated question for how I acquiring the PNGs

Comment: @Maximilian Can you do the capture `cam.camera.capture_continuous` in png? Capturing in lossy jpegs and saving as PNG won't do it, as discussed in the earlier link.

Comment: format="rgb" -> "Write the raw image data to a file in 24-bit RGB format"

Comment: @Maximilian Upload the input images as png and share links?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159080/discussion-between-divakar-and-maximilian).

Comment: The RGB values in the image are uint8, so won't it cause problems with overflow doing `np.linalg.norm(img1-img2,axis=2)` ?I would have thought you need to take `img1.astype(float)` etc don't you?